# Argument list too long for textutil conversion

Tags: command-line, textutils

I am trying to convert all the `.docx` files in a folder into `.txt` files.

I use textutil.

```
textutil -convert txt filepath/*.docx
```

I tried this and got an "Argument list too long" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `find -exec` for this:

```
find filepath \
    -maxdepth 1 \
    -type f \
    -name '*.docx' \
    -exec textutil -convert txt {} +
```

This finds all files that end in `*.docx` in the given directory, and runs the `textutil` command as few times as possible without running into the "argument list too long" error.